# background-size not working. How do I fix the obvious?

Tags: html, css

I'm simply attempting to have a background-image inside a div with the 'cover' size property. No matter what, the image always renders at full size within the div.
Whatever I set in background-size, nothing works.

I've trolled all similar answers on SO but nothing has helped so far.

What am I missing?

```
#page {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  /*padding: 40px 40px 50px 40px;
  position: relative;*/
  z-index: 0;
}
.status {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -5000px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 61px;
}

.Paid {
  background-image: url(<?php echo base\_url();?>assets/blueline/img/status-paid.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


<div id="page">
  <div class="status Paid">
  </div>
```

Comment: the div is 150x61 and background image and correctly behind as a *cover*...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unsure I follow what you're saying.

Comment: see: https://jsfiddle.net/grwy2ux5/ the `Paid` div is 150x61 right? and the `background-image` is applied to that... so the background will have dimensions 150x61 as you have applied `background-size: cover`...

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle showing what you mean? I copied and pasted your css and the backgorund-size did work as expected

Comment: Seems to work in your example.

Here's the image: https://i.ibb.co/ZXDC1ds/status-paid.png
Here's what it's displaying like in the top left of an invoice: https://i.ibb.co/dpSq4Jm/Screen-Shot-2019-04-25-at-10-31-55-am.jpg

Comment: [Scaling background images - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images#cover) says: "The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so that it is as small as possible...". Maybe check the size of the element using dev-tools.

Comment: The problem is nothing in the background-size property works. I've tried background-size: 10px 50px; and background-size: 100% 100%;
To make things more complicated the code is rendered into a PDF so I can't use dev-tools whilst I edit live.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#page {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  padding: 40px 40px 50px 40px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.status {
position: absolute;
text-indent: -5000px;
width: 150px;
height: 61px;
}
.Paid {
background-image: url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51zLZbEVSTL._SX425_.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
<div class="status Paid"></div>
</div>
```

There may be a couple of reason as to why your background isn't working. You didn't quite specify what isn't working however here are my recommendations:

**1. Your image location may be incorrect**
             Check your console to see if there is a 404 error for the file path of the 
             background image, I can't quite pinpoint the exact issue in your code, but 
             take a look at your console and see. It may be your image location.

**2. Remove the background-position: center**
Comment this out and check again because centering your image in a div tag that will be covered by this image is kind of useless. So try removing it.

**3.Change background-size to 100% 100%**
Personally I was playing around with the background size and 100% 100% worked for me. Give it a shot and it should work.

I hope this was helpful, if you require any clarification at all please don't hesitate to comment :) .

I've attached a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

1. The location is fine as the image renders. To check I have used a direct URL to the image which had no effect on background-size property. This is code from a live-rendered PDF so I can't use the console to troubleshoot.

2. Removed and had only this effect: https://i.ibb.co/7rXnzZ9/Screen-Shot-2019-04-25-at-10-52-51-am.jpg

3. Tried this and also had no effect

Comment: Could it be the image itself then because my example worked. Try a different image and let me know please.

Comment: is there a parent div element to the div element with background-size: cover . If so is it styled, because that may be what is causing the issue.

Comment: Just thought that too. Edited original post to include surrounding DIV. only other parent is <body> tag.

Comment: I added it to my answer and it still seems to work, try changing the link to not be brought in through PHP but rather directly from your files. IE `url("/images/picture.png")`

Comment: Have tried a direct link, no php. Same issue. I'm flummoxed.

Answer (score 0):

the `width` and `height` is wrong, try using

```
.status {
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: -5000px;
  width: 172px;
  height: 51px;
}
```

but, why not just use text and border instead?